# Delegación de eventos para clases

Tags: javascript, eventos

tengo un contenedor padre CardContainer y sus hijos con clase="card", y quiero delegar el evento para esa clase. He intentado con el siguiente codigo.

```
cardContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   if(e.target.classList.contains('card')){
      console.log('click');
   }
})
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Adjunta el código completo JS y HTML para darte una respuesta mas acertada, también has mención de los errores o problemas que has tenido.